# TensorFlow: Is dequeue_up_to slower than dequeue_many in tf.train.batch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

In the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/input.py#L744) on GitHub, If I use `allow_smaller_final_batch=True` in `train.batch`, `dequeue_up_to` is used instead of `dequeue_many` for all batches. Is `dequeue_up_to` slower? I cannot find the source code for this somehow even after a search in the TensorFlow repository. I have traced the `dequeue_many` and `dequeue_up_to` functions up till this file [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a0d784bdd31b27e013a7eac58a86ba62e86db299/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py#L440) but I cannot find what is `gen_data_flow_ops` and its functions, and a search in the repo only returns results of `gen_data_flow_ops` getting imported. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficulty tracing code Python code paths through to C++ ops is an unfortunate consequence of TensorFlow's op wrapping technique. Generally the C++ implementations are named FooBarOp, while the Python ends up calling foo_bar in generated code.

In this case [gen_data_flow_ops._queue_dequeue_up_to_v2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py#L509) is an automatically generated Python wrapper for the registration of [QueueDequeueUpToV2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_ops.cc#L372), which is an alias for the C++ [DequeueUpToOp](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_ops.cc#L318).

To answer your original question, there is unlikely to be any significant performance difference from the queue itself (the UpTo version of dequeue only does something different once the queue is closed). Enabling `allow_small_batch` will remove some static shape information from the graph (batch sizes), however, which could conceivably make some ops downstream a bit slower if they optimize based on static shapes.